# Best way to include a standalone tikz file and scale it without scaling the nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

Consider something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\includestandalone[scale=2]{myfile}
\includestandalone[scale=1.5]{myfile}
\end{document}
```

where `myfile` is a standalone file containing a tikz picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right]{$X$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My problem is, that the scale option scales the whole picture including nodes and the characters like $X$ in my example. What is the best way to change this such that I can scale the picture without scaling the nodes? I.e. the equivalent to the scale option of the tikzpicture environment without the `transform shape` option?

Comment: Can you just put the draw commands in the file? Then you could use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]\input{tikzfile.tex}\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 6):

Why not something like this?

```
\newcommand*\MyScale{1}
\newcommand*\Scale[1][1]{\renewcommand*\MyScale{#1}}
\tikzset{%
  every picture/.style={%
    scale=\MyScale,
  }
}
```

This defines a command `\Scale` which takes a single optional argument. By default, it just sets the scaling to 1. With an argument, it sets it to that value. This is then used at the start of each `tikzpicture` to scale the picture without, of course, scaling the text and labels.

So you can then say

```
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
  \Scale[2]
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
  \Scale[1.5]
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
  \Scale[3]
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
  \Scale
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
```

to produce

[image: unscaled nodes]

I would like this to reset the default scaling each time. However, I can't figure out a straightforward way to do that right now and the feature doesn't seem to be worth the additional hassle involved in using a non-straightforward strategy.

Complete code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-tikz.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right]{$X$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone,tikz}
\newcommand*\MyScale{1}
\newcommand*\Scale[1][1]{\renewcommand*\MyScale{#1}}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=\MyScale}}
\begin{document}
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
  \Scale[2]
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
  \Scale[1.5]
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
  \Scale[3]
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
  \Scale
  \includestandalone{\jobname-tikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\def\Scale{3}
\pgfmathparse{1/\Scale}\edef\InvScale{\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\Scale]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right]{\scalebox{\InvScale}{$X$}};
\draw (0,-0.25) -- (1,-0.25) node[right,scale=\InvScale]{$X$};
\draw (0,-0.5) -- (1,-0.5) node[right]{$X$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I am not sure if it works with `\includestandalone` command.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this. Why the use of `\scalebox`? Why not just `scale=\Scale` passed to the `tikzpicture`? Though it would be much better to use `\newcommand*\Scale{3}. Especially since `\Scale` seems just the kind of thing a package might define.

Comment: `scalebox` is just an example that may be used. Nevertheless, I would use the second approach. `\newcommand*\Scale{3}` if of course a better choice, `\def` was used just as a shortcut.

Comment: But wasn't the original problem that the nodes were scaled? If you put stuff which uses `\Scale` inside the nodes, you don't avoid their being affected by the scaling factor....

Comment: Well... The nodes are scaled and also the draw with `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\Scale] ... \end{tikzpicture}`. That is why then I scale each node individually with `scale=\InvScale`. So only the `\draw` will effectively been scaled.